# Why does "std::async" not work as expected?

Tags: c++, lambda, std, c++17

```
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

template<typename Callable, typename... Args>
void Async(Callable&& fn, Args&&... args)
{
    auto fn_wrapper = [](Callable&& fn, Args&&... args)
    {
        invoke(forward<Callable>(fn), forward<Args>(args)...);
    };

    // ok
    fn_wrapper(forward<Callable>(fn), forward<Args>(args)...);

    // ok
    async(forward<Callable>(fn), forward<Args>(args)...);

    // error : no matching function for call to 'async'
    async(fn_wrapper, forward<Callable>(fn), forward<Args>(args)...);
}

void f(int, int) {}

int main()
{
    Async(f, 1, 2);
    this_thread::sleep_for(1min);
}
```

The following code is ok:

> ```
>   fn_wrapper(forward<Callable>(fn), forward<Args>(args)...);
> ```

The following code is also ok:

> ```
>   async(forward<Callable>(fn), forward<Args>(args)...);
> ```

However, the following code is **NOT** ok:

> ```
>   // error : no matching function for call to 'async'
>   async(fn_wrapper, forward<Callable>(fn), forward<Args>(args)...);
> ```

The last case fails to compile with the following error:

```
main.cpp:27:5: fatal error: no matching function for call to 'async'
    async(fn_wrapper,
    ^~~~~
main.cpp:36:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Async<void (&)(int, int), int, int>' requested here
    Async(f, 1, 2);
    ^

  [...]

/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/../../../../include/c++/6.3.0/future:1739:5: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Fn = (lambda at main.cpp:12:9) &, _Args = <void (&)(int, int), int, int>]: no type named 'type' in 'std::result_of<(lambda at main.cpp:12:9) (void (*)(int, int), int, int)>'
    async(_Fn&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)
```

**Why does the last case not work?**

Comment: And how did you *expect* it to work? What happens when you build or run the program? What problems do you have? By now you *should* [know how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Removed the [c++11] tag since `std::invoke` didn't exist back then.

Comment: @xmllmx Explain in words what your expectations are and why the standard is supposed to agree with your expectations. Make a story that people will understand before looking into your code.

Comment: I have reworded my question. @TheQuantumPhysicist

Comment: @xmllmx I retracted my close vote.

Comment: Wow, that's quite a harsh reception. Thanks at least for an actual MCVE :)

Comment: Could it be that a lambda expression is not really a function (it's an object with a operator() member function), so it cannot be used as a function pointer...?

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius Any `callable object to call`, not only an ordinary function pointer, is acceptable in `std::async`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perfect forwarding (`&&`) works only in template argument context. But your lambda is not a template. So `(Callable&& fn, Args&&... args)` just slaps `&&` onto every argument and actually means "pass by rvalue reference", which isn't going to perfect-forward properly.

But more importantly, `std::async` calls the functor as `INVOKE(DECAY(std::forward<F>(f)), DECAY(std::forward<Args>(args))...)`, so the deduced functor's parameter types are actually *decayed* `Callable` and `Args`.

Try this wrapper instead:

```
    auto fn_wrapper = [](auto&& fn, auto&&... args)
    {
        invoke(forward<decltype(fn)>(fn), forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
```

Comment: Should it be `auto&&` to ensure perfect forwarding?

Comment: Your suggested wrapped does not compile:
- 'Args': parameter pack must be expanded in this context.
- 'std::forward': non of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types'
- 'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found